# What is the correct way to put a link in template file?

Tags: magento2.3, megamenu

I have customised the mega menu and integrated it on my Magento site. Now, I need to link the categories links to its corresponding categories.

What is the correct way to link the categories in phtml file?

Looking forward your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for link in static page

```
<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}<<YOUR CATEGORY URL KEY>>" target="_self">[Label]</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{store url='YOUR CATEGORY URL KEY'}}" target="_self">[Label]</a>
```

Thanks